# how do I prevent a script loaded into irb from keeping previous values?

Tags: ruby, irb

This seems very strange to me but I have a script that I'm running that is somehow keeping previous values from previous `load`s of the script. The values in `req1` aren't being dumped on successive loads of the script.

Here's the script:

```
require 'amazon_product'

req1 = nil 
req1 = AmazonProduct["us"]

puts req1.inspect

req1.configure do |c|
  c.key    = "[...]"
  c.secret = "[...]"
  c.tag    = "[...]"
end

puts req1.inspect

req1 << {
    'Version'                => '2010-11-01',
    'Operation'              => 'ItemLookup',
    'SearchIndex'            => "Books",
    'Keywords'    => 'Corrections'
    #, 'A' => 'B' 
}
puts req1.inspect

resp = req1.get

File.open( File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 
      "amazon_response.xml"), 'w') {|f| f.write(resp.body) }
```

Here are the steps:

- open irb (via rails c)
- run the script via the load command
- **uncomment** the A=>B line
- run script again
- **comment** the A=>B line
- run script again

At the end the `req1` object will have  `'A' => 'B'` in it. I'm unclear on why this would be happening since it looks like I'm creating a new object on every run on of the script. It appears that the object is being remembered on every run.

What's the best practice to prevent this sort of thing? I've tried a few things but feel like I'm grasping at straws since I don't understand why it's happening in the first place.

Comment: It'd depend on what AmazonProduct[] actually does. You're not creating anything, you're referencing AmazonProduct["us"].

Comment: That makes sense, but would it be cached across loads? The source is here: http://rubydoc.info/github/hakanensari/amazon_product/master/AmazonProduct#%5B%5D-class_method. The 'us' is passed into a @requests object. Is this happening because the AmazonProduct object doesn't have a .new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not restarting irb, so it depends on what `AmazonProduct[]` does. [From its source](https://github.com/hakanensari/amazon_product/blob/master/lib/amazon_product.rb#L20):

```
def self.[](locale)
  @requests[locale] ||= Request.new(locale)
end
```

It's caching, creating a new request *iff* one doesn't exist yet.

From one standpoint, it's "because it doesn't have a `new`". `new` is only called when the locale hasn't been loaded yet. From another, it's less `new`/not-`new`, but caching, without documenting it may do so.

Given the behavior, it's a reasonable assumption--and why my first thought was `[]`'s implementation.

---

Regarding not restarting `irb`: if there isn't a mechanism to reload the cache (I didn't check), quickest thing to do would be to monkey-patch `[]` and always retrieve a new `Request` for a given locale.

Comment: I read the source, but it still seems like `irb` would be running each script in some sort of throw away context so objects wouldn't have that kind of cross talk.

Comment: It makes testing it a real pain in the neck. You have any suggestions for forcing the object to be fresh without restarting irb?

Comment: @jcollum Probably too late, but added comment regarding a work-around :)